Fatal error during migration to add an enum field
I'm migrating my two SwiftData models to a V2 VersionedSchema.
In this migration, I do the following changes:

Change two field types
Change a Relationship deleteRule
Add a field with a Codable enum for type

Models
V1
    @Model
    class DM1 {
        var a: Date
        var b: Date
        var c: Int
        @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \DM2.dm1) var d = [DM2]()
    }
    
    @Model
    class DM2 {
        var dm1: DM1?
        var e: String
        var f: Date
        var g: Int
        var h: String
        var i: Bool
    }

V2
    @Model
    class DM1 {
        var a: Date
        var b: Date
        var c: TimeInterval? // changed
        var j: EnumJ // added
        @Relationship(deleteRule: .noAction, inverse: \DM2.dm1) var d = [DM2]() // changed
    }
    
    @Model
    class DM2 {
        var dm1: DM1?
        var e: String
        var f: Date
        var g: TimeInterval // changed
        var h: String
        var i: Bool
    }

Migrations
    static let migrateV1toV2 = MigrationStage.custom(
        fromVersion: SchemaV1.self,
        toVersion: SchemaV2.self,
        willMigrate: { context in
            let previousDm1 = try context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<SchemaV1.DM1>())
            let previousDm2 = try context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<SchemaV1.DM2>())
            
        for dm1 in previousDm1 {
            let newDm1 = SchemaV2.DM1(
                a: dm1.a,
                b: dm1.b,
                j: .aValue,
                c: TimeInterval(dm1.c)
            )
            context.insert(newDm1)

            for dm2 in dm1.d {
                let newDm2 = SchemaV2.DM2(
                    e: dm2.e,
                    f: dm2.f,
                    g: TimeInterval(dm2.g),
                    h: dm2.h,
                    i: dm2.i
                )
                newDm2.dm1 = newDm1
                context.insert(newDm2)
            }
        }
            
        try context.save()
        }, didMigrate: nil)

EnumJ
    enum EnumJ: Codable {
        case aValue
        // Only one case is here for now
        // This enum is for future features
    }

Configuration
    container = try ModelContainer(
        for: DM1.self, DM2.self,
        migrationPlan: MigrationPlan.self
    )

Problem
When running the app on a simulator with the database V1, the app crashes with the following error:
Fatal error: Expected only Arrays for Relationships - EnumJ
After clearing the app data, removing the need for a migration, the app works fine.
I just can't get the migration to work.

Why is there no inverse relationship property in DM2? something like var dm1: DM1?

Ands in your migration code you are converting each model separately but you ignore the relationship so that will be lost after the migration.

@JoakimDanielson Thanks for your comment, I guess I'd have encountered a problem one day. I updated my question with my modified structure. However, migration still throws the same fatal error.
